# Ruby on Rails - Not importing SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I'm making a new RoR application while trying to use the bootstrap gem but I've ran into some problems when running it for the first time.
Looks like Ruby is having a hard time including the scss file

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Visitor#index
Showing */app/views/layouts/guest.erb where line #8 raised:

identifier '(function(opts, pluginOpts) {return eval(process' undefined
```

**Guest.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FooBar</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.*scss***

```
 * ...........
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
@import "bootstrap";
```

**Gem File**

```
ruby '2.4.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
#Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
```

Comment: Your problem may be related to a current issue with duktape on Windows. See the following answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125350/7803990

Answer (score 5):

Remove *duktape* gem from your Gemfile and make sure Node.js is installed or something. There should be a comment for alternatives pointing to https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme .

Answer (score -1):

The message, "identifier '(function(opts, pluginOpts) {return eval(process' undefined" looks like a JavaScript issue. That text matches code found here in this Rails [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/blob/7b44387ebe8799f5be864a051b791268ad80d81e/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb#L24). Unfortunately, I don't know a quick fix to suggest, but since the options for that function takes file names, I'd double check to make sure there are no typos in the stylesheet file names anywhere (ie., the files themselves and wherever they might be referenced).