# Using Bootstrap gem with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a fresh rails project where I only generated a controller. I've followed the directions to install bootstrap according to the bootstrap gem, and I keep getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (identifier '(function(opts, pluginOpts) {return eva
l(process' undefined):
     5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
     7:
     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbol
inks-track': 'reload' %>
     9:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': '
reload' %>
    10:   </head>
    11:

(execjs):1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html
_erb__511219785_80461480'
```

I've followed all the instructions according to this webpage: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

My code:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'

# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

# app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
@import "bootstrap";
```

Note, I also did remove *= require and *= require_tree from the application.scss and I did make sure that it's a scss file and not a css file.

Comment: You might want to check out this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/issues/157) and see if it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Not importing SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552742/ruby-on-rails-not-importing-scss)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a current issue with ExecJS and duktape on Windows.

See the following link for more information: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/issues/157

In short, to resolve this issue you can simply remove/comment out duktape from your Gemfile. If you're going for Node.js as your JS runtime, remember to actually install it (Node.js).

If you still have problems, remove all `//= require` directives from your application.scss and keep those in application.js instead.

#### application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

#### application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

#### Gemfile

Remove `gem 'duktape'`

```
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

From a comment on the issue:

> duktape has become the default JS Runtime in Windows sometime ago in
>   rails/rails#30014.
>
> If you look into other similar issues involving Exejs you might found
>   out that duktape is actually the culprit (however its execjs here for
>   definition of duktape context). If you change your runtime environment
>   to use Nodejs, the error would be resolved, as the case with
>   @yasunari89
>
> ## In `config/boot.rb` ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
>
> You can find more info in #152 , #153 and #155 . However, above issues
>   with invalid regex was fixed with new version of duktape, for more
>   info visit judofyr/duktape.rb#41 The new version which resolved the
>   invalid regex issue , started causing issue which you are encountering
>   now. This issue happens because ( as defined in execjs) duktape
>   doesn't support complex contexts and full JS as identifier.
>
> However a PR is under review that will possibly resolve the issue,
>   thanks to @judofyr

You should also make sure that your `application.html.erb` is setup correctly. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <title>title</title>

        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ExecJS supports several runtimes, not just duktape and NodeJS. 
https://github.com/rails/execjs

> ```
> ExecJS supports these runtimes:
>
> therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby
> therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby
> Duktape.rb - Duktape JavaScript interpreter
> Node.js
> Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X
> Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)
> Google V8
> mini_racer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby
> ```